# Css parse order improve performance

Tags: css

Would css parse quicker if it was in the order that its needed on page?
If so what sort of difference would it make and are there any online tools that would sort it in order?

Comment: No, because a CSS parser has no knowledge of anything but the CSS it is parsing. I suspect you mean something else other than "parsing", but it's not clear exactly what.

Comment: I think the benefits would be so small and so dependent on how the CSS Parser relates the information to the browser that it's practically negligible.

Comment: I see. What about minifying, would the performance results also be quite small?

Comment: I just meant would the page load faster if the css was in order as needed.

Answer (score 0):

As others have said, as far as CSS parsing goes, I would assume this to be negligible. However, **this is definitely true for HTML when loading JS or CSS**. It becomes especially noticable when downloading from multiple CDNs.

If you are concerned and can host the site on either github.io or your own webpage, use [Google Pagespeed Insights](https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/) to benchmark performance on more basic things.

Comment: Yeah i use pagespeed insights and pingdom to name a few. I get around 2.6-3.2 secs load time for parts of the us but then other countries jump up to 5. So just looking at ways to increase load times, especially on mobile.

Comment: @Techagesite You should strive for pages that load near instantly. If it takes more than a second then you should try to improve it. 2.5 to 5 *seconds* is way too long; people will just close the tab and go elsewhere, especially if your website has a lot of pages.

Comment: Have you considered reducing the size of the images or their quality? It might also be helpful if you can specify their width and height ahead of time in the HTML? Perhaps if you could tell us the name of the website so we could run Pagespeed Insights ourselves we could be of more assistance! And then we could peek at the source code too!